# I have published a free app on playstore, without ads. Now I want to place ads in an update of my app. Is it possible?

Tags: android, ads, mobile-application, google-play-console, android-update-app

I am a  new developer. I have just published my first two apps on playstore. The second one displays ads as I have placed ads sdk in the gradle file. but my first app does not show any ads, because I published it as a free app on playstore without any ads. But now I want to add ads in my first app too. How can I do it ? Should I delete it and upload again ? Or can I upload a new version of it with ads ? [This is the second app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nasir.jalal) The second app is already showing ads successfully. [This is the first app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nasir.kalasha) It was published as an app without ads. But now I want to place ads in it. Can I place the ad in an update ?

Comment: You can refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70693468/can-i-add-ads-in-my-app-after-published-in-play-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply to answer. **Yes**
You can update new release of APK with Ads
The updated version of the app should be signed with the same key used for signing the previous release else the APK you upload will be considered as new APK and not as updating one

Comment: Thankyou for your comment ! But one more thing to know, the app is currently on playstore as "No Ads". If I place an ad in the update version, how to change the category to "Includes Ads" ?