# Can I add ads in my app after published in play store

Tags: android, flutter, admob, ads

I have created app and I want to publish in play store. And then I think I will add ads in my app after get some users. Is it possible.What I need to do before first time publish?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because app stores are off-topic

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable Ads from play console (Policy -> App Content -> Ads)
   [image]

2. Create AdMob Account : https://admob.google.com/home/
3. Use https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads plugin to show ads

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can add ads in app after deployed on playstore.

1- Get you appId and adsId from addmob account.
2- Give your AppId in manifest.
3- Use google_mobile_ads pakkage for integrate

After integrate the ads it will take 1 2 days to go live.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but the most preferable add ads before publishing on play store